# python write incorrect file data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question about the python read files(its format as txt ). I read a file and argv[1] is once read bytes number, and then put it sotre in a list, but when I write it on another file, it is not the same as the original files. how could i fix this?
readfile:

```
fh = open(file_name, "rb")
imfor = fh.read(mss)
file_content = []
file_content.append(imfor)
while (imfor):
    file_content.append(imfor)
    imfor = fh.read(mss)
fh.close()
```

write File

```
fh = open("test1R.txt", "wb")
for currContent in file_content:
    fh.write(currContent)
fh.close
```

Comment: What is the value of `mss`?

Comment: The issue is that when you read your file, you append the first part into your file_content twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to use a the `with open` context manager to read and write files. You also don't need to manually append the contents to a list. `file.readlines()` does that for you.

Here is a some code to help you with that:

```py
from sys import argv

# we first check if the file exists 
try:
    print("reading file")
    with open(argv[1], "r") as input_file:
        file_contents = input_file.readlines() # stores the file content in an array
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"File {argv[1]} not found")
    exit(1)

# check if the user provided a name for the output file
try:
    out_file = argv[2]
except IndexError:
    out_file = "outfile.txt"

# write to the new file.
with open(out_file, "w") as out:
    try:
        out.write("\n".join(file_contents)) # converts the array back to string
        print(f"Wrote to {out_file}")
    except FileExistsError:
        print(f"{out_file} already exists.")
        exit(1)
```